# JSP Ajax Servlet - Get returned value in JSP

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have two tables, and one of the tables is loaded when i click the first..
So i use Ajax in my JSP for do it :

```
  $("#tablesorter-demo tr").click(function(){
        $('#tablesorter-demo tr').not(this).removeClass('hilite');
        $(this).toggleClass('hilite'); 
       
        $.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url: "gerer_cf_ad",
           data: "name=test",
           success: function(data){
            
           }
         });
    });
```

In my JAVA :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String  forward = "/geCfAd/acc_getes.jsp";
     
    try {
        if(request.getParameter("name") != null){
            codeCentrale = "5874";
            libelle = "CApes";
            request.setAttribute("codeCentrale ",codeCentrale );
            request.setAttribute("libelle",libelle);
                        }getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(forward).forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

So, I want to get values : libelle and codeCentrale in my JSP for add it in may table but I  can't ..

My table code  :

```
 <td id="td_codeCentrale SPCentrale" > <% if(request.getAttribute("codeCentrale ") != null){
                                                                                out.print(request.getAttribute("codeCentrale "));
                                                                            } %></td>
                                    <td id="td_libelleCentrale" ><% if(request.getAttribute("libelle") !=null){
                                                                        out.print(request.getAttribute("libelle")); 
                                                                    }%></td>
```

Comment: url: "gerer_caf_adherente" that does not seem right to me. Is this a servlet?

Comment: yes it is a servlet ..

Comment: doh, of course it is, the doPost() shows as much. I got a bit confused by you mentioning only JSPs. Perhaps you are getting an exception, that 'e.getMessage()' does absolutely nothing. Replace that with e.printStackTrace()

Answer (score 4):

You can get it from two ways.

1) Either you get it from request or session

In JSP Page write following code to get value.

```
String value = session.getAttribute("libelle"); OR
String value = request.getAttribute("libelle");
```

2) you Can pass value in Ajax Response.

on Servlet write following code.

```
out.println(libelle);
```

and in Ajax you will get data in response.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "gerer_caf_adherente",
       data: "name=test",
       success: function(data){
        alert(data);  // your response will print here.

       }
     });
```

Comment: Ok, but in my java file I do request.setAttribute("libelle",libelle); but I can't get it in my JSp ..; if I do request.getAttribute("libelle"); ==> it's not worked

Comment: Actually there might be the attribute value is not set in that case.
you can use session to put that value and try weather it working or not.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSP code runs server-side, your JS code runs client-side. They can't communicate directly, only via HTTP requests.

The request object is a Java abstraction representing a single request. Saving an attribute on a request is just a convenient way to pass data around within the server's handling of an HTTP request, it is discarded as soon as the request completes ,so you don't get request attributes after AJAX.But,It doesn't affect the server's response to the HTTP request so you can print the data in Response.

To pass information from the server to the client via an AJAX request you must include that information in the response.

So on java side write the data in response using:

```
out.println(libelle);
```

And in Javascript you will be able to get data in response

```
$.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: "gerer_caf_adherente",
   data: "name=test",
   success: function(response){
    alert(response);  // you will see the data in alert, you can use it    anywhere
   }
 });
```